# How to make nested dictionary from multiple list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested

I did tried but its saying object is not iterable can anybody fix it?
I actually want to convert list into nested dictionary where year will be my main key

```
a = ['1980', '1982', '1985', '1986'] 
b = ['Alex', 'Bob', 'John', 'David']
c = [9.99, 8.55, 7.66, 6.66],[5,7.5,8.5,9,5],[7.5,8.5,9,5],[7.5,8.5,9]
```

`dic = dict(zip(*a,*b,*c))`

Output I needed below.

```
{'1980':{'Alex':9.99,'Bob':8.5,'John':7.6,'David':6.66},'1982':{'Alex':5,'Bob':7.5,'John':8.5,'David':9} …….. So on for every year which is main key.
Thanks for the help
```

Comment: please, make sure your input and expected results are correct, so we can better understand the needed behavior

Comment: What should be the result for the year 1985 in this case? There are no more values in the input, they are all used up for 1980 and 1982.

Comment: Actually the values for each person has more than 10 in my assingment I just type few there to understand how to make nested...you can see in 'c' list where I elongated few more input data

Comment: I updated the data set

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Did you try writing some `for` loops and using plain dictionary insert operations?

Answer (score -1):

```
final_dict = {}
year_num = 0
for year in a:
    final_dict[year] = {}
    person_num = 0
    for name in b:
        final_dict[year][name]=c[person_num+(4*year_num)]
        person_num+=1
    year_num+=1
```

That should work

Comment: For this to work though it needs to have all the values for each year and not so on.

Comment: I Updated the data set with all year values check it again

Comment: I put the wrong variable name for person so that should work now.

Comment: bro why u have putted here 4*year_num….. I have a problem with code now... actually for each year the value for each 'Name' getting increase by +1 times so its not selecting the correct value for each Name after iteration....no worries with 1st iteration but 2nd, 3rd and so on hasn't selected correct